# Длительное зависание при сохранении внесенной в вопрос правки

Tags: дефект, правки

Использую браузер Vivaldi 1.10.867.48 (Stable channel) (32 бит).

При попытке сохранить внесенные правки в вопрос [Собственная страница для ошибки 401](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691692/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-htaccess)
(правка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/691692/2), я столкнулся с тем, что сохранение правки зависло секунд на 10 или больше.

Зависанием я называю блокирование кнопки "Сохранить" и долгую анимацию загрузки.

По истечению пресловутых 10 секунд правка все-таки была сохранена.

При этом в консоли красуется ошибка:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Request Blocked) ados

Где `ados` ссылка вида:

```
https://engine.adzerk.net/ados?t=1499931924296&request={%22Placements%22:[{%22A%22:22,%22S%22:0,%22D%22:%22adzerk267057611%22,%22ATA%22:[5,17],%22DynamicSiteOverride%22:%22ru.stackoverflow.com%22,%22Z%22:[56016]}],%22Keywords%22:%22php%2Cjavascript%2Chtml%2Ccss%2C.htaccess%2Cx-user-registered%2Cx-user-highrep%2Cx-host-ru.stackoverflow.com%2Cx-cross-site-stackoverflow.com%2Cx-cross-site-serverfault.com%2Cx-persona-frontend%22,%22Referrer%22:%22https%3A%2F%2Fru.stackoverflow.com%2F%22,%22IsAsync%22:true}
```

Из дополнений стоит:

- AdGuard Антибаннер
- EditThisCookie
- LastPass
- ZenMate (неактивен)

С подобной ошибкой за сегодняшний день сталкиваюсь не впервые.

Comment: Попробуйте воспроизвести в другом браузере **и** в том же браузере на чистом профиле. Подозреваю противорекламные средства.

Comment: @Squidward, ошибка наблюдалась в тот конкретный день. Намеренно воспроизвести не получалось в последнем Firefox с теми же дополнениями. Уже на следующий день не мог воспроизвести и в исходном браузере. Дополнение не обновлялось

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что баг не воспроизводится.